# How to sort colours in R

Tags: r, colors

I've generated a vector of hex colour codes using colorfindr.

I would like to sort them by colour from light to dark.

A quick  search has revealed that this is not a simple issue, for example: https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/09/30/colour-sorting/ or https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87588/how-to-sort-colors-properly

The colour vector I am working with is:

```
my_colours <- c("#F6F5F5", "#F4F3F0", "#EDF2F0", "#E1E2E3", "#C2D3DD", "#F6F1E5", 
"#404965", "#E4CCD0", "#DFC575", "#D14845", "#E8B426", "#DF7B6D", 
"#8DBAD3", "#C44334", "#DE7E31", "#BCBFCD", "#9E4049", "#97372F", 
"#BC9AB0", "#4E3427", "#132021", "#0273AD", "#1D3F59", "#F9E892", 
"#E2A4AF", "#F6E8D3", "#A5B774", "#A38074", "#6B847E", "#61ABCC", 
"#6F86AC", "#B2BC3D", "#718E43", "#077A85", "#28A8C4", "#1D7B51", 
"#A57D35", "#3483B0", "#F7CA0E", "#F9CE73", "#FDE35C", "#FAE214", 
"#F4DDD2", "#F4C8BE", "#F5BD87", "#F3B61E", "#F2A581", "#F38387", 
"#F3A72F", "#F3952F")
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

I have tried niavely sorting the hex colour codes in {my_colours} but this does not really improve the order.

Any pointers or guidance to address this query in the context of R would be most welcome.

Comment: Put them in some color space (e.g., HCL, HSV, RGB), and then either sort them along those dimensions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To "sort" color in a pleasing way where similar colors are grouped together, we can try to do find the shortest path that connects all colors in a color space. This turns out to be the same as the famous traveling salesman problem. Here's a quick way to do this is in R using the RGB color space:

```
# original colors
ggplot2::qplot(x = 1:50, y = 1, fill = I(my_colours), geom = 'col', width = 1) + ggplot2::theme_void()
```

[image]

```
library(TSP)
rgb <- col2rgb(my_colours)
tsp <- as.TSP(dist(t(rgb)))
sol <- solve_TSP(tsp, control = list(repetitions = 1e3))
ordered_cols <- my_colours[sol]

ggplot2::qplot(x = 1:50, y = 1, fill = I(ordered_cols), geom = 'col', width = 1) + ggplot2::theme_void()
```

[image]

You can use different color spaces to get different results.

---

Edit:
Sorting from light to dark is much easier, just use Lab space:

```
lab <- convertColor(t(rgb), 'sRGB', 'Lab')
ordered_cols2 <- my_colours[order(lab[, 'L'])]

ggplot2::qplot(x = 1:50, y = 1, fill = I(ordered_cols2), geom = 'col', width = 1) + ggplot2::theme_void()
```

[image]